# Implementing ToString does not override the original ToString method despite using Overridable/Overrides. What do I miss?

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, overriding

I guess, VB's `Overridable` and `Overrides` specifiers do not work how I thought they do.

There are 3 generations from which the other classes inherit: `Grandfather`, `Father` and `TestOverrides`.

```
Public Interface IElements
    Function ToString() As String
End Interface

Public Class Grandfather
    Implements IElements
    Private _MyArg As String
    Public Sub New(Arg As String)
        _MyArg = Arg
    End Sub
    Public Overridable Function IElements_ToString() As String _
        Implements IElements.ToString
        Return _MyArg
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Father
    Inherits Grandfather
    Implements IElements
    Public Sub New(Arg As String)
        MyBase.New(Arg)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function IElements_ToString() As String _
        Implements IElements.ToString
        Return MyBase.ToString
    End Function
End Class

Public Class TestingOverrides
    Inherits Father
    Implements IElements
    Public Sub New(Arg As String)
        MyBase.New(Arg)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function IElements_ToString() As String _
        Implements IElements.ToString
        Return MyBase.ToString
    End Function
End Class
```

Their constructor serve to store a value in a private property, and their (overridden) `ToString` method, implemented as an interface's method, attempts to retrieve this value.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim oTest = New TestingOverrides("x")
        Console.Write(oTest.ToString)
        'produces: SSML.TestingOverrides. Why not "x"?
    End Sub
End Module
```

However, the debugger is not even entering `oTest.ToString`. What do I miss?

Comment: Why would you define an interface with a `ToString` method when every type already has a `ToString` method inherited from `Object`?  I'd not be surprised that, if you change that name to something unique, instead of clashing with an existing method, you'll see the behaviour you expect.

Comment: It seems you've used explicit implementation of the `ToString` method of your interface. Also, you've not overridden the `ToString` method inherited from System.Object, which is the one you called. In order to call the method on the interface, since you've used explicit implementation you have to call it *through* the interface.

Comment: Remove the Interface (unless it's used for something else), use the default override for the `ToString` method (`Public Overrides Function ToString() As String`) , then write:  `Dim myOverride = New TestingOverrides("Some Text") Console.WriteLine(myOverride)`. As of now, you're implementing a method defined by the Interface, not overriding the default `ToString()` method.

Comment: `IElements_ToString` and `ToString` are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call it through the interface, it will work:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim oTest As IElements = New TestingOverrides("x")
    Console.Write(oTest.ToString())
End Sub
```

But, if you call it through the class's type, then you have to use the class's name for the method.  Since, on the class, you declared it as a public method called `IElements_ToString`, that's how you'd have to call it:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim oTest As New TestingOverrides("x")
    Console.Write(oTest.IElements_ToString())
End Sub
```

The only reason calling `ToString` on the class works at all is because all classes inherent a public `ToString` method from the base `Object` type.  If you had used any other method name, it would have told you that the named method doesn't exist.

As others have mentioned... since all types automatically inherit a `ToString` method, it's unusual, unexpected, and confusing to define another one with the same name via an interface.  It would be better to name it something else like `GetValue` or `GetDescription`, or to simply trust all derived classes to override the `Object.ToString` method.  If you really want to force all derived classes to provide a `ToString` implementation, you could force it via your implementation of the `Grandfather` class:

```
Public Class Grandfather
    Implements IElements
    Private _MyArg As String
    Public Sub New(Arg As String)
        _MyArg = Arg
    End Sub
    Public NotOverridable Overrides Function ToString() As String _
        Implements IElements.GetArg
        Return _MyArg
    End Function
End Class
```

Or:

```
Public Class Grandfather
    Implements IElements
    Public NotOverridable Overrides Function ToString() As String 
        Return GetArg()
    End Function

    Public MustOverride Function GetArg() Implements IElements.GetArg
End Class
```